# Braintree Client Token

Tags: javascript, base64, braintree

I'm integrating Braintree using the Drop-in UI.  This is being done in Classic ASP so I have to write this longhand and not use a SDK.

I've successfully received a client token from Braintree but not sure what to pass to the Drop-in UI. Here is what I get back from Braintree ("clientToken" shortened for brevity):

`{"data":{"createClientToken":{"clientToken":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJhdXRob3JpemF0aW9uRmluZ2VycHJpbnQiOiJleUowZVhBaU9pSktWMVFpTENKaGJHY2lPaUpGVXpJMU5pSXNJbXRwWkNJNklqSXdNVGd3TkRJMk1UWXRjMkZ1WkdKdmVDSXNJbWx6Y3lJNkltaDBkSEJ6T2k4dllYQnBMbk5oYm1SaWIzZ3VZbkpoYVc1MGNtVmxaMkYwWlhkaGVTNWpiMjBpZlEuZXlKbGVIQWlPakUyT0RBNE1EQXhPRGtzSW1wMGFTSTZJbUl4TlRrM05Ea3pMVEUxT0VU0QifX0="}},"extensions":{"requestId":"169e6a8e-20a1-4105-8740-7d8461d7dd26"}}`

Then I base64 decode it and get:

`{ "version":2, "authorizationFingerprint":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIwMTgwNDI2MTYtc2FuZGJveCIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLnNhbmRib3guYnJhaW50cmVlZ2F0ZXdheS5jb20ifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2ODA4MDA5NTksImp0aSI6ImY0MjdkMGQ4LWM5NzUtNDAwNy1hOTk5LWJhZWQ2ZjNlM2QxZiIsInN1YiI6IjJxMjQyZHZyeHBkNnFoZjMiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5zYW5kYm94LmJyYWludHJlZWdhdGV3YXkuY29tIiwibWVyY2hhbnQiOnsicHVibGljX2lkIjoiMnEyNDJkdnJ4cGQ2cWhmMyIsInZlcmlmeV9jYXJkX2J5X2RlZmF1bHQiOmZhbHNlfSwicmlnaHRzIjpbIm1hbmFnZV92YXVsdCJdLCJzY29wZSI6WyJCcmFpbnRyZWU6VmF1bHQiXSwib3B0aW9ucyI6eyJtZXJjaGFudF9hY2NvdW50X2lkIjoicHJvZHVjdGNhcnQifX0.STt-mLKt2VD-0LfzQbwxoEoIkUMOG5lyW1zdgU5kJfwaTKHAbPwiTB5p1EGrJQpZoj6hXl1zCSlubaQ2pvFKHQ", "configUrl":"https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443/merchants/xxxxxxxxx/client_api/v1/configuration", "merchantAccountId":"xxxxxxxx", "graphQL":{ "url":"https://example.com/graphql", "date":"2018-05-08", "features":[ "tokenize_credit_cards" ] } ...` 
From the documentation it appears that I'm supposed to pass "authorizationFingerprint" to the Drop-in UI but am not sure.  Should this be passed as is, decoded, etc.? Or something else?

The client code is:

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.36.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>`
  <!-- Step one: add an empty container to your page -->
    <form id="payment-form" action="/route/on/your/server" method="post">
       
        <div id="dropin-container"></div>
        <button id="submit-button" class="button button--small button--green">Purchase</button>
    </form>

`  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

          braintree.dropin.create({
              authorization: '<%=braintreeClientToken%>',
              container: '#dropin-container'
          }, function (createErr, instance) {
              button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                  instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
                      // Submit payload.nonce to your server
                  });
              });
          });
      })
  </script>
```

No matter what form/part of the Client Token being passed, the Drop-in UI does not load/appear.

Comment: The answer is just pass the "clientToken" value without decoding it.

Comment: Write that up as an answer to this question, and mark it as answered.